# Import two datatables into one csv file in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two datatables.One contain employer name and the other contains the employee details.I need these two datatable into csv file.

The format is like the following:

```
EmployerName EmployerCode
XXXXXXXxxx     YYYYYYYY
EmployeeId    EmployeeName  EmployeeCode
1              AAAAAAAA        AA1
2              BBBBB           BB2
.............
```

My code is as follows:but it will export one datatable only.

```
public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dtDataTable, string strFilePath)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dtDataTable.Columns[i]);
                if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                    {
                        string value = dr[i].ToString();
                        if (value.Contains(','))
                        {
                            value = String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
                            sw.Write(value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();   

        }
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to change first line of your method to :

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, true);
```

Then it appends to the file.

Then you should call your method for both data tables:

```
var filePath = @"d:\export.csv";
CreateCSVFile(yourDataTable1, filePath);
CreateCSVFile(yourDataTable2, filePath);
```

> [**StreamWriter(String path, Boolean append)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   Initializes a new instance of
>   the StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default
>   encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either
>   overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this
>   constructor creates a new file.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **path:** The complete file path to write to.
>
> **append:** true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no
>   effect, and the constructor creates a new file.